# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'tblgender' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'giFK'

Tags: sql

```
create database my_data
create table tblperson(
pid int primary key,
pname varchar(15),
pgender varchar(15)
)
create table tblgender(
gid varchar(15) primary key,
gender varchar(15)
)
Alter table tblperson add constraint giFK 
Foreign key (pgender) references tblgender(gid)
```

Comment: I ran this query in SQL Server Management Studio (SQL Server) and it ran without issues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.